# PHP mail errors

Tags: php, ajax, email

Hi guys here below is my entire code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$support_address = "info@bkslegal";
$headers = "From: ".$email;
$header2 = "From: ".$support_address;
$finalmessage = "
From:$_POST[name]
Email:$_POST[email]
Message:$_POST[message]
";

if ( $name == "")

{   
}
else
{
    mail ($support_address, $subject, $message, headers);
    $result = "Your message has been sent succesfully!"


}
?>




<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolltopcontrol.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.44625.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
            $("input").each(
            function(){
            if($(this).val()=="" && $(this).attr("placeholder")!=""){
            $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
            $(this).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("placeholder")) $(this).val("");
            });
            $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val()=="") $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
            });
            }
        });

        $("textarea").each(
            function(){
            if($(this).val()=="" && $(this).attr("placeholder")!=""){
            $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
            $(this).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("placeholder")) $(this).val("");
            });
            $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val()=="") $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
            });
            }
        });

        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So i get an error saying

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /home/bkslegal/public_html/send.php on line 28"

and when i remove that curly bracket i get the following error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /home/bkslegal/public_html/send.php on line 83

I have been sitting for hours trying to resolve this, could someone please help

Comment: add semicolon  after `$result = "Your message has been sent succesfully!`

Comment: missing a semi-colon after `"Your message has been sent succesfully!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here..
You need to add `;` at the end of statement `$result`

```
 mail ($support_address, $subject, $message, headers);
    $result = "Your message has been sent succesfully!";
```